# Powershell directory comparison

Tags: powershell

Is there a way in Powershell to compare 2 directories in detail?

I am working in a webfarm IIS 7.5 system that is being replicated by DFS to web reals.

If I copy a directory in this way (using DFS) the site breaks.  If I copy the identical directory directly to the web real it works fine.

I was thinking something like a bit by bit comparison of the contents of two directories.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Compare-Object`:

```
Compare-Object (gci C:\directory1 -recurse) (gci c:\directory2 -recurse)
```

For scenarios where you want to compare the content of files in two directories, better go with a tool like [`WinMerge`](http://winmerge.org/), it will provide you with a nice GUI to do the comparison and is pretty fast as well.

Comment: Will this just compare the contents of the directories?  Is there a way to compare the contents of each file as well?

Comment: @Acerbity - Yes this is for the files and folders in the directory and will show what is different.

Comment: One more question if you see it.  It gives me a list of files without locations (which is only somewhat helpful).  Can you think of a way to get the full path back on the results I get?  Again thanks in advance.